# How to remove the space between &bigstar and &star and print all the stars in a line?

Tags: css

```
<div class="rating-nogo">&bigstar;&bigstar;&bigstar;&bigstar;
  <span class="half">&bigstar;</span>
  <span class="other half">&star;</span>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.rating-nogo.star4half {
  width: 4.5em;
}
.rating-nogo {
  color: gold;
  text-shadow: black 0 0 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.rating-nogo .half {
  display: inline-block;
  width: .5em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.rating-nogo .other {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  text-shadow: none;
  color: lightgray;
}
```

I'm using this example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/james_alley/kR4jn/)

I need to show something that is shown in 3rd, in the above link. What I need to know is:

- I need to print all the 5star in a one line, but the half coloured star is printed above all the other 4 stars. How to fix this?
- Also when I print, the half coloured star's coloured half and uncoloured part has a bit of gap between them. How can I remove it?

Comment: Use `vertical-align: top` or `vertical-align: bottom` on the `.rating-nogo .half`.

Comment: Thank you :-) is there a way to remove space between coloured half of thestar and uncoloured half of the star

Comment: @mad_ss To remove the space, press the backspace key. Sorry if this sounds silly, but that's the way to do it.

Comment: @mad_ss: The colored and uncolored versions don't seem to of the same size. Try setting `width: .4em` for the same selector mentioned above instead of `.5em`.

Comment: @Mr Lister-when do i need to press backspace, is it when displaying it on the browser, or in the code

Comment: @Harry-what is you mentioned as same selector

Comment: There is no code here that is to do with CodeIgniter

Comment: @MrLister when i press backspace it navigates to the back page doesn't removed the space between stars

Comment: @mad_ss: Same selector means `.rating-nogo .half`. Change the `width` inside its block.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 didn't get what you said

Comment: @mad_ss I meant to remove the actual spaces from the source. The original example that you provided a link to in the question doesn't have spaces between the first half's `</span>` and the second half's `<span>`. Yours does.

Comment: Is there a way to make bigger in size these stars